# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'post_project' Heroku and Django

Tags: python, django, web, heroku, web-deployment

I was going through a tutorial about creation of user accounts and by its end I tried to deploy my website, but I got this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'post_project'

My working directory looks like this

[image]

And this is settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
...
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Most of the time I've adhered to the tutorial section about accounts in "Django For Beginners" by W.Vincent. Yet still I do get this particular error every time I try to deploy.

I attempted to change django version, it didnt help either.

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: Don't just dump code from online without inspecting them! Somewhere in the code you copied, you're imporing that module

Comment: @FalseDev that is a good point, but I double-checked everything for that module - haven't found anything like that, only one of my models is named "Post"

Comment: Provide the full stack trace or a repository link